# I want to replace the words “Billing Address” with “Passenger Information”, How can i do that?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I edit the form-billing.php but it's not working

```
<?php if ( WC()->cart->ship_to_billing_address_only() && WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) : ?>

        <h3><?php _e( 'Billing &amp; Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h3><?php _e( 'Billing Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?
```

Comment: theses things are usually templated somewhere

Answer (score 1):

By the way your question is not clear,

As per my understand this is WordPress plugin and you need to change the language string.

you can see there is a function "_e" and add your string with in that function.

You have mentioned its not working. please compare with your file with original file this.

https://github.com/dafydb/ada/blob/9ab64c164f412e91178a6b5e5874c9cb3759fa07/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php

Answer (score 0):

in file: `woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php`

try replacing:

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

with

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Passenger Information', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using WooCommerce here so I recommend to use the translation mechanism which is described here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/ .

It is **not** recommended to change the source code directly because your changes get lost when you do an update.